PHP Secure LDAP / LDAPS to Azure Active Directory via Microsoft Entra Domain Services
I've got Secure LDAP / LDAPS enabled to Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Entra Domain Services. This is working great in an application I have so I know it's enabled and working fine.
I'm now trying to build a PHP application to grab a list of all users from my Azure AD.
I've been referencing https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php to build this, but I'm not all to familiar with LDAP.
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://ds.example.co.uk")
          or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

This works fine, so I'm assuming I'm able to connect to this server fine. So i then added an LDAP Bind anonymously
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://ds.example.co.uk")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding anonymously
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous failed...";
    }

}

And I get the error

Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /ldap.php on line ##
LDAP bind anonymous failed...

Line ## is $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);
Next I thought this might be because I'm trying to do things anonymously, so I tried with credentials
// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'firstname.lastname@example.co.uk';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'passwordexample123!';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://ds.example.co.uk")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

However I still get an error. this time

Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /ldap.php on line ##
LDAP bind failed...

Line ## is $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
Any advice on where I should begin to either
A) find the problems here? Either in Entra's logs or server logs? (Console shows nothing.)
B) assuming it's a syntax issue - anything obvious here?
I think the OU for this would be a default AADDC Users according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/domain-services/synchronization however I don't know the syntax for putting this into the mix.

A few details can make all the difference:

specifying the port
specifying the 'ldap://' prefix (or ldaps://)
specify the user's domain

Try specifying them as in the code below to check.
$LDAPHost = 'ldap://domain:389';
$LDAPUser = 'domain\ldap-user';
$LDAPPassword = 'xxx';

$ldap = ldap_connect($LDAPHost);
ldap_bind($ldap, $LDAPUser, $LDAPPassword) or die("Could not bind to LDAP");

Also check that the specified LDAP user is authorised to read the directory (not expired, locked, no change password at next login, etc.).
